# Complex query annotation for each distinct

Tags: django, django-orm

In `PurchaseOrder` list view I would like to display the total `quantity` grouped by each distinct `unit`. I'm using the following models and function but there's a database hit every time `get_quantity_by_unit()` is called - for each object in the list.

```
class PurchaseOrder(models.Model):
    lines = models.ManyToManyField(
        Product, blank=True, through='PurchaseOrderLine' related_name='%(class)s_line')

    def get_quantity_by_unit(self):
        return PurchaseOrderLine.objects.filter(purchase_order=self).values(
           'unit__abbreviation').annotate(sum=Sum('quantity'))

class PurchaseOrderLine(models.Model):
    purchase_order = models.ForeignKey(PurchaseOrder)
    product = models.ForeignKey(Product)
    quantity = models.DecimalField()
    unit = models.ForeignKey(Unit)
```

Can this be achieved with django orm?

The following gets the total quantity but not for each distinct `unit`:

```
query = PurchaseOrder.objects.filter(date__gte=cutoff_date).annotate(
    total=Sum('purchaseorderline_order__quantity'))
```

The following throws `ValueError: Prefetch querysets cannot use values().`

```
queryset = PurchaseOrderLine.objects.values(
    'unit').order_by('unit').annotate(total=Sum('quantity'))
query = PurchaseOrder.objects.filter(date__gte=cutoff_date).prefetch_related(
    Prefetch('purchaseorderline_order', queryset=queryset, to_attr='totals'))
```